# Is there a way to rescale an image to fit a specific form in a canvas on React canvas context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, canvas

I have two images: the image "a", which is the main canvas, is a blank space with an irregular polygon that has four sizes. [image: image "a"].
Image "b" is a regular photo of a dog. [image: image "b"].

Now, I want to transform image b into the form of the polygon in image "a", merge the edited image "b" within the polygon of image "a" and making the result of that in a new image "c", that will be displayed on the page. for that, I'm trying with the following code in React, using canvas context:

```
const ImageMerge = () => {
    const canvasRef =useRef(null);
  const [image1, setImage1] = useState(truck1);
  const [image2, setImage2] = useState(null);
  const [mergedImage, setMergedImage] = useState(null);

  const image2Ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (image2) {
      mergeImages();
    }
  }, [image2]);

  const handleImageUpload = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      setImage2(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  const mergeImages = () => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = image1;
    img1.onload = () => {
      canvas.width = img1.width;
      canvas.height = img1.height;

      // Draw image a
      context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

      if (image2Ref.current) {
        const img2 = new Image();
        img2.src = image2Ref.current.src;
        img2.onload = () => {
          // Reduce image b size
          const resizeWidth = canvas.width * 0.29;
          const resizeHeight = (img2.height / img2.width) * resizeWidth;

         // Draw image b
         context.save();
         context.setTransform(1, 0.04, -0.09, 1, 0, 0);
         context.rotate(2 * Math.PI / 180)
         context.drawImage(img2, 390, 65, resizeWidth, resizeHeight);
         context.restore();

          // Get the resulting merged image
          const mergedImageUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
          setMergedImage(mergedImageUrl);
        };
      }
    };
  };

  return (
    <div className="test-container">
      {mergedImage ? (
        <img src={mergedImage} alt="Merged Image" />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageUpload} />
          <p>
            Click here to upload your image
          </p>
          {image2 && <img ref={image2Ref} src={image2} alt="Image 2" />}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageMerge;
```

but for some reason, it does not transform image b as required.
Is there a way to do this with this code?

Thanks in advance.